# Ios Msal Cannot access keychain group error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

I am working on Xamarin app that uses MSAL library to authenticate to Web API that is secured by Azure AD. When I run my code in simulator I get this error.

The application cannot access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (the TeamId is null)

```
  _pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
           .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
           .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
           .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}")
           .Build();
```

I already added com.microsoft.adalcache to my Entitlement.plist but I still get the error when debugging.

```
<dict>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work by selecting my Entitlements.pslist in the Custom Entitlements

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, done. Please upvote my answer.